# ZeroMQ: How to set the HWM to become really a "zero" ( not the API def'd 0 == INFINITY )?

Tags: zeromq, low-latency

I have a question about the high water mark (**`HWM`**) for a ZeroMQ **`PUB/SUB`** connection. Effectively I want to set the `HWM` value to zero.
 i.e.: if a message can't be delivered, just drop it.

Unfortunately it seems that the `HWM` value can only be set as low as **`1`**.
"**`0`**" means infinity according to the API docs and my testing.

In my opinion, using "`0`" to mean "***infinite***" in the API was a mistake
:/ 
It's probably unlikely to change.
**Is there a workaround that
doesn't require recompilation of `ZeroMQ`?**

The problem I'm encountering is that with a non-zero `HWM`, when a connection fails, at least one message sits in the queue and is sent when the connection is re-established. By that time the message is no longer valid and shouldn't be trusted.

I've thought about discarding messages on the receiving side by including a time stamp generated at the sending side. Unfortunately the systems clocks are not connected to the internet and drift significantly. Syncing the clocks with an additional **`REQ/REP`** socket will introduce other complicated startup states to the sender and seems like an unnecessary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes:

### <sub>. . . may try to hunt the same deer from the opposite forest</sub>

Based on the need,

 declared in the initial problem motivation,

 the solution may be derived from setting not the `ZMQ_???HWM`,

but another parameter:

> **`ZMQ_CONFLATE`**: Keep only last message
>   
>  Default value `0` ( false )
>   
>  Applicable socket types    **`ZMQ_PULL`**, **`ZMQ_PUSH`**, **`ZMQ_SUB`**, **`ZMQ_PUB`**, **`ZMQ_DEALER`**
> <sub>**If set**, a socket shall **keep only one message** in its inbound / outbound queue, this message being the last message received/the last message to be sent. Ignores `ZMQ_RCVHWM` and `ZMQ_SNDHWM` options.
> Does ***not*** support **multi-part messages**, in particular, only one part of it is kept in the socket internal queue.</sub>

and some help may come from a "preventive-measure" hidden in:

> **`ZMQ_IMMEDIATE`**: Queue messages only to completed connections
>   
> Applicable socket types all, ***only*** for connection-oriented transports.
>   
> <sub>**By default** queues will fill on outgoing connections even if the connection has **not** completed. This can lead to "lost" messages on sockets with round-robin routing (REQ, PUSH, DEALER).
>   
> **If** this option is **set to 1**, messages shall be queued only to completed connections. This will cause the socket to block if there are no other connections, but will prevent queues from filling on pipes awaiting connection.</sub>